# How to ignore object field in Angular7

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular7

How can I tell Angular to ignore one or more fields before the http call; like the `@JsonIgnore` in java.

Example:

I have this object: `{id: 1, libelle: 'test', mustIgnore: 'test'}`;

I expect this object to be : `{id: 1, libelle: 'test'}`;

I tried `delete object.field`, but I'm looking for a simpler way to do it, like using an annotation on my object.

Because if I have an array of objects, it becomes more difficult to manage it.

**EDIT :**

I do not want to do this manually for every object! Is there a way to just specify the fields that I want to delete and do it automatically, whenever I have a different object with different fields to delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ES6 [`object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get an immutable object without the desired property.

```js
const obj = {id: 1, libelle: 'test', mustIgnore: 'test'};

// Destructure into mustIgnore and rest properties
const { mustIgnore, ...rest } = obj;

const projectedObject = rest;
 
console.log("old", obj);
console.log("new", projectedObject);
```

Comment: I do not want to do this manually for every object! because I have different object with different fields to delete

Comment: @EssaidiM this wont delete the fields but it will create a new object with those properties excluded

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array, you can simply map like:

```
const ignoreArray = array
    .map(
        a => ({ id: a.id, libelle: a.libelle })
    )
```

As a result you have an array of objects with only `id` and `libelle`.

EDIT: 
Based on Kunal answer, a better approach would be:

```
const ignoreArray = array
    .map(
        obj => {
            const { mustIgnore1, mustIgnore2, ...rest } = obj;
            return rest
        }
    )
```

Where `mustIgnore1`,`mustIgnore2`, etc. They would be the fields to eliminate

Comment: I do not want to do this manually for every object! Is there a way to just specify the fields that I want to delete and do it automatically, whenever I have a different object with different fields to delete

Answer (score 1):

If your data set only contains key+value combinations, you can create a new empty object {} and loop through all the members of your original object with a for loop and check for each key with an array of key names you want to ignore. If the item is in the array, skip it, if it is not you add it to your new object.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [
{id: 1, libelle: 'test1', mustIgnore: 'ignore1'},
{id: 2, libelle: 'test2', mustIgnore: 'ignore2'},
{id: 3, libelle: 'test3', mustIgnore: 'ignore3'}
];


const newArray = [];

for (element of array) {
    const { mustIgnore, ...rest } = element;
    newArray.push(rest);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Another way:

```js
const array = [
{id: 1, libelle: 'test1', mustIgnore: 'ignore1'},
{id: 2, libelle: 'test2', mustIgnore: 'ignore2'},
{id: 3, libelle: 'test3', mustIgnore: 'ignore3'}
];

 const newArray = array.map(obj => {
                const { mustIgnore, ...rest } = obj;
                return rest;
 });


 console.log(newArray);
```

Please look [`object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) for further reference, but this is pretty much it!